# postfix/smtpd : timeout after connect from

Tags: postfix

I have a problem with a postfix, i have an error in my mail.log

`postfix/smtpd[12802]: timeout after CONNECT from nm4-vm1.bullet.mail.ne1.yahoo.com[98.138.91.44]`

I am not so sure about what happened, its happen to mail provider like yahoo,gmail or outlook.

this is my postfix configuration so far

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = yes
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
compatibility_level = 2
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = mail.our-mail.com, localhost, localhost.localdomain, our-mail.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 192.168.1.0/24 192.168.2.0/24 192.168.103.0/24 [::1]/128
mynetworks_style = subnet
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = mail.hwg.web.id ESMTP
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous noplaintext
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your connection is not stable (or a firewall is blocking something).
Yahoo try to connect, successful, but doesn't send anything because it is waiting for your server.
Check your connection and your firewall logs, you will see the reject for the packets after the first one.

Comment: mikrotik was blocking the port.